# Visual Studio not creating edmx file using Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Im trying to use Entity Framework on my .NET 4.0 Web Site. I already have installed Entity Framework 6.1 and i "Add New" ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my site using a valid connection string , and I select my table. I know this is a valid table with several columns and rows of data. After the creation is finished I am left with only a .cs file with no properties and a new connection string added to the web.config, but there is no .edmx file created. I know the SQL user in the Con String has read/write permissions and this is a valid table. Any clue as to what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: Does the table contain supported data types and does it have a proper primary key? (Some deprecated data time like (n)text are not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the values of this new connection string with your values?

Take a look of this link and retry..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx

PS: I think that you should have created a "Project" and not a "new WebSite" using:
"Folder>New>Project> ASP Web App" in VS

Doing this you have all ready to go (references, EF etc..) then you could even start from a empty virgin model, or EF designer from database where you could easly manage or create entities, relations etc.